# shared_from_this and thread safety

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is it thread-safe to call `shared_from_this` in multiple threads?

[cpppreference state](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this):

> Effectively executes std::shared_ptr(weak_this), where weak_this is the private mutable std::weak_ptr member of enable_shared_from_this.

Can I take it as a guarantee that it's safe to call `shared_from_this` in multiple threads?

Take the following code as an example:

```
class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<A> clone() {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
};
```

In this case, can I call `A::clone()` in multiple threads?

Comment: Yes `shared_ptr`s are thread safe

Comment: Probably not. The key fact here is that `weak_this` is mutable (i.e. non const).

Comment: I still _believe_ it should be safe. If I got it right, this case is explicitly mentioned in the [std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr() - Notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr#Notes) (but I struggle to realize the definite answer in this).